# Updating local_policy.jar or US_export_policy.jar for IBM Domino Server

Tags: java, security, servlets, lotus-domino

I've developed a number of servlets (OSGi plugins) running under a patched Domino 8.5.3 server.

I'd like to do some basic encryption/decryption of data and I'd like to avoid the "InvalidKeyException : Illegal Key Size" error which is resolved by upgrading the local_policy.jar & US_export_policy.jar files in notes\jvm\lib\security directory.

I'm not sure if Domino relies on the files that are shipped by IBM in the Domino Installer and if upgrading these files cause an issue.

I can log a support call with IBM if this isn't a common requirement.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I did, and I didn't write it down, but yes upgrading those files will resolve the problem.  As I recall, there were updated JARs I got from IBM.  There may also be something you need to do with the java.policy file as well.